# AngularJS view not refreshed after model change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm displaying some data on a table using Angular and I'm loading it asynchronously from json with $http. I have a date-picker and when the user selects a different date, the view has to display the data for that date. 
The problem is that even if the new data is correctly loaded, the view is not refreshed.
Here is my code (I simplified including only important lines):

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in tableKPI"> 
        <td ng-repeat="index in tableKPIColsInt">{{ row[index]}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="index in tableKPIColsFloat">{{ row[index] | number:2}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Where tableKPIColsInt and Float are just lists of strings with column names.

```
loadDailyDataFromJSON = function ($plantName,$http,$scope,$timeout) {

    var formattedDate = dateFormat($scope.selectedDate,"yyyy-mm-dd");

    $http.get("json/"+formattedDate+".json")
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.tableKPI = response.data[$plantName];
    },
    function(error) {
        $scope.tableKPI = {};
        console.log("No data for KPI for "+formattedDate);
    });

    // tried also to call $apply
    $timeout(function() { $scope.$apply();}, 500);
};
```

And the controller:

```
app.controller("tableController", function($scope,$routeParams,$rootScope,$http,$timeout){
    $scope.tableKPI = {};
    $scope.reloadData = function(){
        loadDailyDataFromJSON($rootScope.currentPlant,$http,$scope, $timeout);
    };

}
```

This code works the first time I load the page, then if I change the date the new data is loaded correctly, but the view doesn't change.
I know that there are many similar questions, but the solution doesn't work for me.
I tried calling $scope.$apply(), but it gives me the error digest already in progress..
I tried also to call $apply() after a timeout, but I obtain the same result.

[UPDATE] putting the function inside / outside the controller or in a service doesn't change anything.. The function is being called and the data in the variable is updated.

Maybe there is a problem with the model? As I do a double nested loop and I take both the info for displaying (one iterates over the rows and one over the string indexes). If I put this code specifying the controller nothing works:

```
<tbody ng-controller="dailyCtrl as dc">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in dc.tableImbalance"> 
        <td ng-model="row[index]" ng-repeat="index in dc.tableImbalanceCols" ng-bind-html="row[index].toString()"></td> 
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Primarily, why you took out `loadDailyDataFromJSON` function outside controller? Could you reproduce this problem in plunker/fiddle?

Answer (score 3):

Refactor it like this

```
 app.controller("tableController", function($scope,$routeParams,$rootScope,$http,$timeout){
    $scope.tableKPI = {};
    $scope.reloadData = function(){
        loadDailyDataFromJSON($rootScope.currentPlant,);
    };


  // assuming the function is in same file as controller 
    loadDailyDataFromJSON = function ($plantName) {

        var formattedDate = dateFormat($scope.selectedDate,"yyyy-mm-dd");

        $http.get("json/"+formattedDate+".json")
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.tableKPI = response.data[$plantName];
        },
        function(error) {
            $scope.tableKPI = {};
            console.log("No data for KPI for "+formattedDate);
        });

    };

}
```

But if you prefer the service approach

```
app.service("testService", function($http){

 this.loadDailyDataFromJSON = function ($username) {

     var endpoint = "rooturl"+"json/"+formattedDate+".json";
      return $http({
        method: 'get',
        url: endpoint 
      });
    };

}
```

And in controller

```
 app.controller("tableController", function($scope,$routeParams,$rootScope,testService{
        $scope.tableKPI = {};
        $scope.reloadData = function(){
            var formattedDate = dateFormat($scope.selectedDate,"yyyy-mm-dd");

            testService.loadDailyDataFromJSON (formattedDate)
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.tableKPI = response.data[$plantName];
            },
            function(error) {
                $scope.tableKPI = {};
                console.log("No data for KPI for "+formattedDate);
            });
        };


    }
```

If `formattedDate` is not null and you have used the correct `rooturl` then this will work like charm

Comment: `$http.get` does `$apply` implicitly, I don't understand what is the need of explicit `$apply` here?

Comment: I tried but it gives error, as $http is already doing the digest process

Comment: do you get data ??

Comment: Yes if I log the dictionary is correctly updated.. But the view doesn't refresh

Comment: I've used your code, and implemented it like a service.. Same result.. I think that the problem is on the template..

Comment: `tableKPI`  where are you using this in view

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `$timeout` or `$scope.$apply` when you are using `$http` service. 
This functionality already implemented inside `$http` service.

Make sure you used your controller right.

This is an example with your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/jgyombzg/5/

When you click Reload you will see what data updated.

[UPDATED]

Due question update I think the reason is `ng-bind-html`
Take a look into fiddle again - you can see 2 `ng-repeat`

- in 1 case i just used `ng-bind`
- in 2 case i used `ng-bind-html`

Second is empty as you can check.

Can you try do the same? If you will have same result -
 [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) 
might help

Comment: what do you mean by you used your controller right? My code is the same as yours, expect for the fact that I use a nested ng-repeat.

Comment: try to change  `ng-bind-html` for `ng-bind` and let me know what happens.

Comment: the problem is not there since I have other templates, with the same code for loading data and the view doesn't get updated as well..

Answer (score 0):

Put loadDailyDataFromJSON in angularservice and inject the same into your controller and start using it. then apply is not required as am using the same concept in my application. it is perfectly working without apply

Comment: I tried putting the function into a service, same result. Maybe the problem is two nested ng-repeat

Comment: Your template has the same structure as mine with nested and INDEPENDENT ng-repeat?